# How can I perform click events in a select dropdown (Angular)?

Tags: html, angular, dom-events, eventemitter

I have two buttons (month, year) that react to different events... Now I would like to insert these events in a select. Can you please tell me how this works?

My Code:

```
// Solution with buttons
<button class="menu-button" type="button" mat-raised-button [ngClass]="{'active': selectedMenuLeft === 'monthButton'}" (click)="activateButton(1)">Monat</button>
<button class="menu-button" type="button" mat-raised-button [ngClass]="{'active': selectedMenuLeft === 'yearButton'}" (click)="activateButton(2)">Jahr</button>
 activateButton(check) {
    if (check === 1) {
      this.selectedMenuLeft = 'monthButton';
      this.navService.sendNavEventUpdate('month');
    } else {
      this.selectedMenuLeft = 'yearButton';
      this.navService.sendNavEventUpdate('year');
    }
  }
```

```
// The same with a select. What do I have to optimize?
<select class="upload_slc" required title="">
<!-- Options -->
<option value="content" *ngFor="let navValue of menuLeftMobile" [value]="navValue">
{{ navValue }}
</option>
</select>
// Menu left in mobile
  menuLeftMobile: Array<string> = ['Monat', 'Jahr'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by [two-way binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding-) to `ngModel` directive.

Controller

```js
menuLeftMobile: Array<string> = ['Monat', 'Jahr'];
selected: string;

onChange() {
  if (selected === 'Monat') {
    this.selectedMenuLeft = 'monthButton';
    this.navService.sendNavEventUpdate('month');
  } else {
    this.selectedMenuLeft = 'yearButton';
    this.navService.sendNavEventUpdate('year');
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<select class="upload_slc" required title="" [(ngModel)]="selected" (change)="onChange()">
  <!-- Options -->
  <option value="content" *ngFor="let navValue of menuLeftMobile" [value]="navValue">
  {{ navValue }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Now you don't need the additional variables `selectedMenuLeft` to set the class. You could use the `selected` in the template.

```html
<div [ngClass]="{'active': selected === 'Monat'}"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-select placeholder="Select Menu" name="nav_value" 
    (selectionChange)="menuChangeAction(nav_value)"
        [(ngModel)]="nav_value">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let navValue of menuLeftMobile"
          [value]="navValue">{{ zone.label }}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
```

In your component you can do the following:

```
nav_value: any;

menuChangeAction(value) {
    console.log(value) // you will get your selected value here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Simplest Way To That Is

```
<select #mySelect (change)='onOptionsSelected(mySelect.value)'>
```

And Function Will Be Like This

```
 activateButton(check) {
    if (check === "Monat") {
      this.selectedMenuLeft = 'monthButton';
      this.navService.sendNavEventUpdate('month');
    } else {
      this.selectedMenuLeft = 'yearButton';
      this.navService.sendNavEventUpdate('year');
    }
  }
```

Hope This Will Work For You